# Smith normal form of powers of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, smith-normal-form

I have been trying to compute the cokernels of powers of integer matrices using Smith normal form.

> When is $\text{Smith}(A^2) = (\text{Smith}(A))^2$ and more generally when is $\text{Smith}(A^n) = (\text{Smith}(A))^n$?

Some numerical experiments showed that this is not always true. Is there at least a good sufficient condition for determining when such a formula holds? Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering of you can get something out of property III on pp.2 of this paper: *Axioms for invariant factors. Queiró, João Filipe. Portugaliae Mathematica (1997) Volume: 54, Issue: 3, page 263-269* [PDF link](http://www.emis.de/journals/PM/54f3/pm54f302.pdf).